# Array of pointers pointer to another array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to create an array of pointers that points to another array of structs.
However, I am confused as to whether I should declare the new array as an int or the same type as the first array since it is going to hold pointers.
This is what I have so far:

```
struct inventoryItem
{
    int itemNumber;
    int itemsInStock;
    float cost;
    float retailPrice;

};


int main()
{
    printf("Enter the number of slots needed in the array: ");
    int size;
    scanf("%d", &size);

    //array of items
    struct inventoryItem *inventory; //use pointer to item 
    inventory =(struct inventoryItem *) malloc(sizeof(struct inventoryItem)*size); //create array to store inventoryItem with size 'size'

    //array of index
    //int *indexArray = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*size); 
    struct inventoryItem *indexArray; //use pointer to item 
    indexArray =(struct inventoryItem *) malloc(sizeof(struct inventoryItem)*size); //create array to store inventoryItem with size 'size'

    //fill array contents
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter item %d number: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &inventory[i].itemNumber);

        printf("Enter item %d stock: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &inventory[i].itemsInStock);

        printf("Enter item %d cost: ", i);
        scanf("%f", &inventory[i].cost);

        printf("Enter item %d price: ", i);
        scanf("%f", &inventory[i].retailPrice);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("Item %d number: %d\n", i, inventory[i].itemNumber);
        printf("Item %d stock: %d\n", i, inventory[i].itemsInStock);
        printf("Item %d cost: %f\n", i, inventory[i].cost);
        printf("Item %d retail price: %f\n", i, inventory[i].retailPrice);
    }


    //struct inventoryItem *header = inventory;
    //struct inventoryItem *ptr = inventory;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        indexArray[i] = &inventory[i]; 
            //problem here, it says "no operator '=' matches these operands"

    }
}
```

EDIT:
Now that I created the array, how can I print the content of inventory using indexArray?

Comment: Unrelated: [Stop casting `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: You're not creating an array of pointers, which would be the first problem. You're creating to arrays of `inventoryItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `indexArray' as

```
struct inventoryItem **indexArray;
```

create it with

```
indexArray =(struct inventoryItem **) malloc(sizeof(struct inventoryItem *)*size);
```

and fill with

```
indexArray[i] = &inventory[i];
```

or

```
indexArray[i] = inventory + i;
```

Comment: how can I print the inventory items' contents using the indexArray?

Comment: Every `indexArray` item is a pointer to an `inventory` item so just use `indexArray[i]->itemsInStock` (or longer, but equivalent, `(*indexArray[i]).itemsInStock`)

Answer (score 2):

You should allocate array of pointers:

```
struct inventoryItem **indexArray;
indexArray = (struct inventoryItem **)malloc(sizeof(struct inventoryItem*)*size);
```

Answer (score 1):

for readability it is better to do a typedef first:

```
typedef struct inventoryItem Inv;
```

If you want to create an array of pointers to the struct array then instead of

```
Inv* indexArray = malloc(sizeof(Inv)*size);
```

write

```
Inv** indexArray = malloc(sizeof(Inv*)*size);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct inventoryItem **inventory; //use pointer to item 
inventory =(struct inventoryItem **) malloc(sizeof(struct inventoryItem*) * size);
```

Answer (score 0):

So far you have two pointers, each of which points to the first item of an array of structs.

If you want an array of `T` then you use the `T[]` notation, it is no different with pointers than with other types. So

```
struct inventoryItem *foo[10];
foo[0] = malloc( size * sizeof *foo[0] );
```

etc. In this example, `inventory` is replaced by `foo[0]`. You could of course then write `struct inventoryItem *inventory = foo[0];`

Of course you can also dynamically allocate `foo` if the number of arrays you need is not known at compile time:

```
struct inventoryItem **foo = malloc( 10 * sizeof *foo );
```